# How to form the below mysql query to laravel query syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery, left-join

Below are my sql syntax, how to implement it in laravel, thanks in advance.

```
SELECT * FROM `tr_policy_privacy` AS pri  
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM tr_policy_full_create as cri WHERE cri.client_id=156 and cri.policy_type_id = 1) 
AS hours 
ON pri.id = hours.policy_template_edit
```

So far i have tried this, but i'am trying to find a way using function inside left join.

```
DB::table('tr_policy_privacy AS pri')
    ->select(['cri.policy_title', 'cri.policy_type', 'cri.policy_std', 'cri.policy_version', 'cri.approved_user_id', 'cri.effective_date', 'cri.last_revised_date', 'cri.id'])
    ->leftJoin(
        DB::raw('(
        SELECT * FROM tr_policy_full_create as pol WHERE pol.client_id=156 and pol.policy_type_id = 1
        ) AS cri'),'pri.id', '=', 'cri.policy_template_edit'
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Can you any tried ? Please try by searching similar topic [like](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries).

Comment: There are lots of similar questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: @tajgeer i have edited.

Answer (score 1):

If your raw sql is correct then try to execute directly in laravel

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM `tr_policy_privacy` AS pri  
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM tr_policy_full_create as cri WHERE cri.client_id=156 and cri.policy_type_id = 1) 
AS hours 
ON pri.id = hours.policy_template_edit";

$result = DB::select($sql);
```

Use DB namespace to the top of class

```
use DB;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i'am trying to find a way using function inside left join.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($slug)
{
  $query =  DB::table('wn_entries')
    ->leftJoin('wn_criteria', 'wn_entries.id', '=', 'wn_criteria.entry_id')
    ->leftJoin('wn_attachment_entries', 'wn_entries.id', '=', 'wn_attachment_entries.entry_id')
    ->leftJoin('wn_team', 'wn_entries.id', '=', 'wn_team.entry_id')
    ->leftJoin('wn_confirmation', 'wn_entries.id', '=', 'wn_confirmation.entry_id')
    ->leftJoin('wn_users', 'wn_entries.user_id', '=', 'wn_users.id')


    ->select(
        'wn_entries.*',
        'wn_entries.id as main_entry_id',
        'wn_criteria.id as criteria_entry_id',
        'wn_criteria.*',
        'wn_attachment_entries.id as attachment_entry_id',
        'wn_attachment_entries.*',
        'wn_team.id as team_entry_id',
        'wn_team.*',
        'wn_confirmation.id as confirmation_entry_id',
        'wn_confirmation.*',
        'wn_users.*'
        );


     $query = $query->where('wn_entries.slug',$slug);


      $entrydata =  $query->get()->toArray();
    $entries  = $entrydata['0']; 
  return view('entries.show', compact('entries'));

}
```

You get an idea from this code.

Comment: No, i didnt get any idea.

Comment: $query =  DB::table('table_1')
    ->leftJoin('table_2', 'table_1.id', '=', 'table_2.id')
    ->select(
        'table_1.*',
        'table_2.*'
        );


     $query = $query->where('table_1.name','abc_name');
      $entrydata =  $query->get()->toArray();

Comment: please check it . in this way you create join query in laravel